# date is saving in different format when saving to database

Tags: java, date

Iam saving date in below format `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy`, but it is saving in this format `2013-05-03 00:38:20.0`. But when i print same date on console before saving to database, it is as expected `INFO: Fri May 03 00:38:20 IST 2013`

Please can anyone explain why it is saving as above mentioned.

Below is the code:

```
Date now = new Date();
String datetimeStr = now.toString();
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
Date parseDate = format.parse(datetimeStr);
```

***Datebase column***

```
date_order_created date
```

Comment: What is the column type (`varchar`, `date`, ...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)
The following code formats a date and time according to the pattern String passed to the SimpleDateFormat constructor. The String returned by the format method contains the formatted date and time that are to be displayed.

```
Date today;
String output;
SimpleDateFormat formatter;

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, currentLocale);
today = new Date();
output = formatter.format(today);
System.out.println(pattern + " " + output);
The following table shows the output generated by the previous code ex
Pattern              Output
EEE, MMM d, ''yy    Tue, Jun 30, '09
```

Answer (score 5):

I *hope* you're not actually saving your dates as text in the database in the first place. Assuming you're not (and I don't think you are), you're not really "saving date in below format" at all... you're just saving the date.

The value of a date doesn't *have* a format - June 19th 1976 is the same date whether I represent it that way, or as 1976-06-19 or 19/06/1976 or 06/19/1976 (assuming I know how to interpret any of those formats). That's what you're seeing here - you're saving the date, and when you look at it "in the database" (e.g. via some SQL console) you're seeing one representation... but when you fetch it from the database and print it from Java, you're seeing the results of calling `Date.toString()`. That doesn't change the *value* at all.

If you want to format a `Date` value in one particular way, use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) - but be very aware that a `Date` object itself has no format (or time zone, or calendar) and your database probably doesn't either. (The exact details of what goes in the database will depend on the database and the column type.)

It's very important to distinguish between a value and string representations of that value.

For example, if I write:

```
int x = 0xff;
int y = 255;
System.out.println(x == y);
```

then that prints "true" - because both `x` and `y` have the same value. The fact that in one case I used a hexadecimal representation doesn't affect the value as a number at all.

Comment: Thanks for very good explanation, so i have to alter the table column to varchar and save the date as Date.toString() rite?

Comment: @developer: Absolutely not! Why would you want to do that? You're just trying to save the date, right? Logically, that's the important data... not the format. Clients should be able to display that data however they want. For example, a US person may want to see MM/dd/yyyy format, and a UK person might want to see dd/MM/yyyy... if you store it in text, that's a problem, but if you store it *as a date value* then you can just format it in the most appropriate way later.

Comment: ok. But my client want me to display it in this format "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" when iam trying to display it, iam getting cann't parse the dateformat . Any suggestion regard this please

Comment: @developer: Well where are you displaying this? Fetch the value, then format it. *Don't* just store the text form. The value isn't naturally text - it's naturally a date.

Answer (score 0):

When you save a Date objet in a database, this is generally not its String representation which is saved. This depends of the field type used in the database.

And :

```
Fri May 03 00:38:20 IST 2013
```

looks like a date.toString()